# Rspec error while trying to create user with Devise token auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

In my users controller. I have

```
module Api;module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, only: [:create]
    before_action :set_user, only: [:destroy, :update, :show]
    before_action :authorize_user, except: :create  


    def create 
     #TODO : fix for simultaneous account and registration create    
      @user = User.new user_params
      @user.save!
      render json: @user,status: :ok and return
    end
    private    

     def set_user
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
     end

    def authorize_user
      unless set_user == current_user 
       render json:{message: "you are not authorized."}, status: 401
      end  
    end 

  end
end;end
```

Now my problem is that in my rspec user contro

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do

it "can create user" do
   post :create, user: {email: "ad@ad.ad",username: "add", name: "dad",
                                                         password: "password", password_confirmation: "password",
                                                         account:{company: "caaad"}}, :formate =>:json

    puts response                                        
end
```

end
But its giving following error to me

```
Failure/Error: render json: @user, status: :ok and return

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

My code is quite simple test not much logics.
Why its not working ?
I even tried to add

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

in spec_helper but still its not working. Please tell me what I am missing ?

Although controller code is correct because it is working with normal Curl request.

in my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create :update_access_token!

 def update_access_token!
    self.access_token = "#{self.id}:#{Devise.friendly_token}"
    save!
  end
```

end

Comment: could you post the complete users_controller.rb and users_controller_spec.rb

Comment: @oreoluwa edited, Please check now

Comment: https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication/issues/220

Comment: Does the approach in the issue fix yours?

Comment: @oreoluwa It does not fix the error but know i know that error is not in my code, it's in devise and rspec config.

Answer (score 0):

That the test is going through in the first place, makes me suspect that there is another `UsersController` within the application, as I would have expected your spec to look like this:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do

  it "can create user" do
     post :create, user: {email: "ad@ad.ad",username: "add", name: "dad",
                                                         password: "password", password_confirmation: "password",
                                                         account:{company: "caaad"}}, :formate =>:json

      puts response                                        
  end
end
```

If that still results in the error, I'd advise that you check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38213997/3893710)

Comment: Thanks, For answer. I was setting up module Api;module V1 before declaring Rspec.describe so it is hitting right UserController. I am editing my question.