# Rails 4 - undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, shoulda

I'm working on a course building a social network using Rails 4 &                                                                                      Devise.

I'm stuck trying to get a course to pass, this is the error I'm getting:

```
1) Error:
UserFriendshipsControllerTest#test_: #new when not logged in should get redirected to the login page. :
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
    test/controllers/user_friendships_controller_test.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <class:UserFriendshipsControllerTest>'
```

This is my users_friendships_controller_test.rb :

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFriendshipsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

context "#new" do
    context "when not logged in" do
        should "get redirected to the login page" do
            get :new
            assert_response :redirect
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My user_friendship.rb:

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "friend_id"

    private

        def friendship_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :friend_id, :friend)
        end
end
```

The only thing I've added to my user_friendships_controller.rb is a blank new method and:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]
```

Please let me know if I should post any more code.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide `user_friendships_controller` listing

Comment: @farhatmihalko
`class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController`
 `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]`
 `def new`

 `end`
`end`

Answer (score 5):

I've found answer in [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)):

> If you choose to authenticate in routes.rb, you lose the ability to
>   test your routes via assert_routing (which combines assert_recognizes
>   and assert_generates, so you lose them also). It's a limitation in
>   Rails: Rack runs first and checks your routing information but since
>   functional/controller tests run at the controller level, you cannot
>   provide authentication information to Rack which means
>   request.env['warden'] is nil and Devise generates one of the following
>   errors:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
NoMethodError: undefined method 'authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
```

> The solution is to test authenticated routes in the controller tests. To
>   do this, stub out your authentication methods for the controller test.

[How to stub authentication.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs)